# My WordPress website has 2 header

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast

My WordPress website has 2 header and showing yoast plugin 2 times in source code. I want to delete one, so that its not show meta tags twice.

Is there anybody can help?

Comment: Do you have wp_head() twice in your theme? If you change the theme to a default one do you still have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove one meta tag that's showing twice then you can fix as like:

> Google Search Console (former Google Webmaster Tools) reports you have duplicate meta titles or duplicate meta descriptions. Each URL should have unique meta tags so this is important to fix as soon as possible.

## Unique URLs With Duplicate Meta Tags

- http://www.example.com/my-favorite-content/
- http://www.example.com/my-favorite-content-again/

If you have multiple unique URLs with the same meta tags, you may decide to:

Change the title of pages to distinguish between the duplicate pages.
Add a Canonical URL to indicate which page search engines should index
Set all but one page to `noindex`.

## Subpages With Duplicate Meta or Title Tags

- http://www.example.com/my-favorite-content/
- http://www.example.com/my-favorite-content/page/20/

If you have paginated URLs with duplicate meta or title tags, you can

- Add the page variable to the metas template for a site-wide fix for pages, posts, or taxonomies that do not have custom meta tags. This variable can be added by going to <kbd>SEO -> Search Appearance -> Content Types OR Taxonomies</kbd> (depending on where the issue is) and making sure the title field has the page variable: `%%page%%`.
- Add the page variable directly to the page, post, or taxonomy for customized meta and title tags.

## Parameter URLs With Duplicate Meta Tags

- http://www.example.com/my-favorite-product/
- http://www.example.com/my-favorite-product/?option=choice

Google has advice on handling duplicate content caused by URL parameters [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080548?visit_id=636862543758867229-273857153&rd=1).

## Other URL Formats

Google has even more advice on handling duplicate content [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/6080547).

---

Follow reference:

1) https://kb.yoast.com/kb/how-do-i-fix-duplicate-meta-tags/